# jQuery Append Ad JavaScript code inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I want to dynamically insert an Ad JavaScript code inside a DIV

The DIV I want to use in the body is:

```
<div class="madv" id="madv"></div>
```

The Ad JavaScript code that needs to be inserted inside the DIV:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write('<scri' + 'pt type="text/javascript" src="'
   + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://uat-secure' : 'http://ad-cdn')
   + '.technoratimedia.com/00/81/95/uat_19581.js?ad_size=300x250"></scri' + 'pt>');
</script>
```

**The problem is** that the JavaScript code contains many double quotes, single quotes and comments which prevents it from rendering correctly.

**What I need ?**
A script code using jQuery or any other method to pass the javascript Ad code above from HEAD to the DIV in the BODY. Use this : http://jsfiddle.net/0rnyhpcx/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.write('<scri' + 'pt type=text/javascript src='
   + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://uat-secure' : 'http://ad-cdn')
   + '.technoratimedia.com/00/12/34/uat_123456.js?ad_size=300x250></scri' + 'pt>')
```

Comment: I want to pass it from the <head> tag to the <div> in <body>

Comment: @JosephRaphael http://jsfiddle.net/0rnyhpcx/1/ ? Appear to return status code `457 Section inactive` ? , type `text/plain` ?